# Contact form doesn't send body message for anonymous users

Tags: 8

I'm having a problem with contact form module, from core 8.9.5.

I've created a contact form:

- if I send a message with admin user, recipient gets the email with all fields, also "body" message
- if I send a message with anonymous, recipient get the email without the "body" message

I can't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Why "-1"? I can't understand..

Comment: do you use webform? show me yml or screenshot of the handler.

Comment: No, i'm using Contact module from core

Comment: Did you have a look on your logs /admin/reports/dblog (when database logging is activated)? Do you use some kind of mail module? I had some trouble when using Mime Mail, SMTP module and Mail System together when sending HTML mails

Comment: I'm using SMTP but there aren't logs. And sending email works, but not the whole email.. I'v switched to webform..